# How can I run a crumbling ground hazard?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, terrain, environmental-hazards

This is something I see in the movies that I want to use: *People are running while the ground crumbles beneath their feet. Sometimes they need to stop, take a few steps back, and launch themselves from the crumbling part to relative safety.*

This could be a sinkhole forming or an ice bridge breaking up while they cross it. Why it's crumbling is less important than that it is crumbling.

**How can I add such a hazard into my game?**

I've looked at the difficult terrain rules and they don't really seem suitable. (For one, creatures can't run across difficult terrain.) I also want to avoid using grid-based tactical detail for this because I'd rather not track exact distances. **I'd like to narrate this but use dice determine how difficult it is to navigate the shifting, unstable ground.** I just don't know, rule-wise, how to handle that.

Another wrinkle that I'd want to be able to handle is work animals pulling things like a cart or dogsled. I imagine that would change things compared to individuals running and leaping.

Are there official rules specifically for this? Can this be handled using the general rules — if so, how? If nothing in the existing game rules can handle this, are there any well-tested house rules for crumbling terrain hazards?

Comment: Thank you for helping to clarify the question @sevensideddie

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my campaign I had the bridge completely disappear at X number of feet per turn, while they had to make dex checks to see how far they could move over the crumbling part of the bridge. 
(DC 20 to run with no penalty, fail to move at only half speed)
I also had an acrobatics check with a DC of 10, and if they failed it they fell prone at the *end* of their turn.
 Basically, they had to move fast enough over the crumbling part to avoid being caught in the fallen part of the bridge.

I'm not sure if you could call it "well tested" as I have only tested it once, but you could change the DC of the check if you wanted it to be easier or harder. It may be important to note that no characters died, although one of the enemies did fall and die.

Comment: This is probably made or broken by how you describe it. If you do use it, make sure that your descriptions feel epic and exciting, as that is clearly what you are going for. Make it more than just a mechanical challenge.

Comment: RE acrobatics: jump/tumble in 3.5 nyo?=)  I like the idea of incorperating jump checks.  Some of the epic movie moments I've seen are when people jump, almost don't make it and have to cling to the edge.  Or they just fall as things crumble around them...

Answer (score 1):

I would advice the use of skills:

Run is used to stay (just) ahead of the crumbling zone, jump and/or tumble could be used to navigate and/or save oneself from damaging effects (usually falling). Reflex saves can be made to avoid falling as a last resort.

Note that creatures pulling vehicles are usually burdened with a moderate or heavy load, limiting their abilities to run. Not to mention many other skills related to movement.

Some things unmentioned in your question are party level and access to magic items. Both are particularly important factors towards the CR of the encounter in this case.
For example; A ring of feather falling for the heavily armored Dwarven cleric would nullify the danger of falling, unless (s)he would be right over a pool of lava, in which case gently floating lower would still be quite hazardous.

Personally, I like to limit such encounters for the situations I want to impede freedom of movement for the party (e.g. to limit their resources / force them to keep going forward during an adventure), or as a part of a strategy of an end-boss.